# Como criar método em C# para fazer insert de 2 Query SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Como criar um método no c# para inserir dados, esse método fazer mais de um INSERT um atras do outro?

Porque eu tentei aqui e não deu certo!

Comment: Pode sim, poste o que fez pra gente tentar te ajudar.

Comment: Estou no busão, mas, minha ideia era criar duas variaveis no metodo e atribuir query's nessas variaveis e depois ativar o metodo com algum botão no win forms apenas isso

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,

Eu fiz da seguinte forma e funcionou na boa para mim.

Segue exemplo:

```
    public static void InsereDadosArqTxtRetSaidaDAL(out string pstrMsg, out bool pbooRetorno, ArrayList parrHeaderArqTxt, List<ArrayList> plstItensArqTxt)
    {
        pstrMsg = string.Empty;
        pbooRetorno = false;

        SqlConnection conn = ConexaoBD.CriarConexao();

        // Inseri dados na tabela de cabeçalho
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uspCtzInsertConfirmPedProcess", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cd_rejeicao", parrHeaderArqTxt[1]));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nu_ped", parrHeaderArqTxt[2]));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dt_hrs_inclusao", parrHeaderArqTxt[3]));

            SqlParameter nuRetornoID = cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cd_confirmPedProcess", SqlDbType.Int));
            nuRetornoID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            SqlTransaction tran = cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.Transaction = tran;

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Capturando o último ID de retorno do parâmetro OUTPUT
                int nuCdPedProcess = (int)nuRetornoID.Value;

                using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("uspCtzInsertConfirmItPedProcess", conn))
                {
                    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd2.Transaction = tran;

                    foreach (ArrayList itensArqTxt in plstItensArqTxt)
                    {
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cd_PedProcess", nuCdPedProcess));
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cd_rejeicao", itensArqTxt[1]));
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cd_mercadoria", itensArqTxt[2]));
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@qtde_mercadoria_ped", itensArqTxt[3]));
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@qtde_mercadoria_ok", itensArqTxt[4]));

                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        cmd2.Parameters.Clear();
                    }
                }
                tran.Commit();

                pbooRetorno = true;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                tran.Rollback();

                pstrMsg = string.Format("Erro:\nMétodo: 'InsereDadosArqTxtRetSaidaDAL'\nDetalhes: {0}", ex.Message);

                pbooRetorno = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: o que acontece se este método for chamado milhares de vezes e ocorrer um erro no `cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction`?

Comment: Acredito que poderia dar um erro. Pelo que entendi, teria que abrir a transação dentro do bloco try, caso ocorra o erro o bloco catch faz o tratamento necessário ?

Comment: O melhor seria colocar tudo dentro de um `using (var tran = new TransactionScope)`, não abrir a conexão dentro do `CriarConexao()`, deixe que o método chamador decida a melhor hora de abrir a conexão e por fim, instancie ele usando um using: `using (var conn = ConexaoBD.CriarConexao())`

Comment: Toby no caso a forma de implementação vai mudar correto ? Porque Estou fazendo o teste e começo aparecer alguns erros de sintaxe, consultei no msdn nesse link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, e vi que tenho que mudar a estrutura  do método é isso mesmo ?

Comment: segue um exemplo (não testado): http://codepaste.net/e915p9

Comment: Toby, implementei o exemplo ainda não consegui testar, mas eu vi que tem ajustes no código acredito que dessa forma vai ficar melhor. Porém tenho dúvida em relação ao rollback da transação caso tenha algum erro. O próprio bloco  using (var tran = new TransactionScope()) já faz esse tratamento automaticamente, ou  no caso eu teria que seguir sua dica que está no bloco catch e, deixar o erro subir e tratar isso fora ? E a questão do return true ou false, o método não aceita porque ele foi declarado como void. Eu teria que mudar para bool ou continuaria passando uma parâmetro output como antes ?

Comment: Diego, falha minha, esqueci de mudar a assinatura do método para retornar um boolean. o TransactionScope vai dá um RollBack caso o Complete não seja chamado, ou seja, saiu do using da transação e não teve Complete, então é feito um RollBack automatico.

Comment: Show de bola, assim que eu tiver um txt no FTP do cliente, faço download e testo o método e ti dou um feedback. Obrigado pelas dicas.